# The import *** cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have the following pom file that generates class files from XSDs. These are included in he generated JAR file.  I tried to create a unit test in this Eclipse  project that uses one of the generated files, but after running "mvn install" and when importing the package, the package still can't be resolved.  I tried to clean the Eclipse project and update Maven.  I extracted the JAR file and it has the class in there.

Test file:

```
import gov.hhs.fha.nhinc.common.nhinccommonadapter.RespondingGatewayCrossGatewayQueryRequestType;
```

Extracting the JAR file:

```
mvn clean install
cd target
jar xvfz *.jar>
 inflated: gov/hhs/fha/nhinc/common/nhinccommonadapter/RespondingGatewayCrossGatewayRetrieveResponseType.class
```

pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.connectopensource</groupId>
    <version>4.0.7</version>
    <artifactId>CONNECTCommonTypesLib</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>CONNECT common types</name>


    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:${git.username}/Common-Types.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:${git.username}/Common-Types.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/${git.username}/Common-Types</url>
        <tag>4.0.7</tag>
    </scm>

    <developers>
    </developers>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.4</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>CONNECT License Agreement</name>
            <url>http://www.connectopensource.org/product/licensing</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7-b53</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb22-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
                    <strict>${xjc.strict}</strict>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>nhinc/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>docs.oasis-open.org/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>ebRS/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>ihe/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>nhin/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>oasis/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>uddi/uddi_v3.xsd</include>
                        <include>uddi/uddi_v3custody.xsd</include>
                        <include>uddi/uddi_v3policy_instanceParms.xsd</include>
                        <include>uddi/uddi_v3subscriptionListener.xsd</include>
                        <include>uddi/uddi_v3subscription.xsd</include>
                        <include>www.w3.org/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>xmlsoap.org/**/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>Endpoint/**/*.xsd</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <testSource>1.6</testSource>
                    <testTarget>1.6</testTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>apache-snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache SNAPSHOT Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <xjc.strict>false</xjc.strict>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Directory structure:

```
/src/main/resources
/src/test/java
```

This appears to be a problem with Eclipse, because I was able to run "mvn install" from the command line, and it built successfully and ran the test.

Comment: Share your directory structure.

Comment: @shi, I updated the question.  It appears to be an Eclipse issue, because I have no problems with running the commands from the shell.